# clojure.tools/namespace refresh fails with "No namespace: foo"

Tags: clojure, namespaces

I'm using [tools.namespace](https://github.com/clojure/tools.namespace) to provide smart reloading of namespaces on the REPL. However, when calling `refresh` or `refresh-all`, it throws an error.

```
user=> (require '[clojure.tools.namespace.repl :as tn])
user=> (tn/refresh)
:reloading (ep31.common ep31.routes ep31.config ep31.application user ep31.common-test ep31.example-test)
:error-while-loading user

java.lang.Exception: No namespace: ep31.config, compiling:(user.clj:1:1)
```

And it seems to end up in this weird state where `(require ep31.config)` works without an error, but afterwards the namespace isn't actually defined.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I kind of figured this out, this seems to be a combination of circumstances

- there were AOT compiled classes left in `target/classes` from doing `lein uberjar` previously
- tools.namespace doesn't function correctly when loaded namespaces are AOT compiled
- `target/classes` is by default on the classpath

So long story short, if you did a `jar`/`uberjar` build before, then remove `target/` and things should start working again.

The question I haven't been able to solve yet is why `target/classes` is on the classpath to begin with. I'm suspecting it's being added by Leiningen, but haven't found yet where or why it's happening.

Comment: This is correct. Leiningen puts `target/classes` on the classpath by default  for two reasons: 1) to make compiled Java sources available to the application, and 2) the output directory for AOT-compilation (`*compile-path*`) must be on the classpath.

Comment: So if you did a `lein clean` after doing `lein uberjar` you would not encounter your problem? Or rather did `lein clean` as soon as you got into a bad state such as described in your question.

Comment: I deleted my `build/clojure` directory (I'm using the gradle plugin) and restarted my REPL and that fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I learned this the hard way, documentation for `:target-path` says (https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj#L309-L313):

```
;; All generated files will be placed in :target-path. In order to avoid
;; cross-profile contamination (for instance, uberjar classes interfering
;; with development), it's recommended to include %s in in your custom
;; :target-path, which will splice in names of the currently active profiles.
:target-path "target/%s/"
```

I guess there has to be legacy reasons that `:target-path "target/%s/"` isn't the default.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18777954)

Comment: Good point! Included the documentation for `:target-path`, now the answer should make more sense (the documentation is quite succinct on describing the problem).